# WordPress Admin Ajax is forcing HTML links to be outputted text

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a simple HTML link which I am passing thru AJAX using WordPress's `admin-ajax.php`

```
<a href = "http://example.com">Hello World</a>
```

But when received on the server side, the link now looks like this:

```
<a href="\"http://example.com\"">Hello World</a>
```

I am guessing admin-ajax.php is forcing the links to be outputted as text. I am also having similar issue with HTML `<img>` tag.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, simply wrap the HTML content with stripslashes()